# Why are certain restrictions morphisms of prevarieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

At page 30 the author of [this book](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf) states that the restrictions $f_{\mid f^{-1}(U_i)}$ are morphisms of prevarieties. Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: What are you thoughts so far? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is the distinguished open set $D(x_i) \subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)$. By Lemma 1.50 on p. 24, $f^{-1}(U_i)$, as an open subprevariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)$, is isomorphic to the affine variety corresponding to the $k$-algebra $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]_{x_i}$ (the localisation of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ at $x_i$). Let $g : U_i \to \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ be the map defined by 
$g(x_0:\ldots:x_n) = (x_0/x_i,\ldots,x_{i-1}/x_i,x_{i+1}/x_i,\ldots,x_n/x_i).$ By Corollary 1.60 on p. 28, this map is an isomorphism of prevarieties. The composite map $h = g\circ f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)} : f^{-1}(U_i) \to \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ induces the homomorphism of $k$-algebras $\phi : k[y_1,\ldots,y_n] \to k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]_{x_i}$
given by
$$ \phi(y_j) = \begin{cases} x_{j-1}/x_i & \text{for} \quad 1\leq j \leq i\\ x_j/x_i & \text{for} \quad i < j \leq n\end{cases}$$
Therefore, $h$ is a morphism of affine varieties, by Proposition 1.44 on p. 22. Since $g$ is an isomorphism, we conclude that the composite map $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)} = g^{-1}\circ h : f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is a morphism of prevarieties (in fact, of affine varieties).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I realized that I still have some problems with the topics before (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832937/simple-questions-about-projective-space)). Therefore I'll check out this answer later.

Comment: I think, now I roughly got it. You used the (ii)=>(iii) direction of Prop. 1.44, didn't you? Btw: How do we get now that $f$ itself is a morphism of prevarieties?

Comment: Let $f_i:=f_{|f^{-1}(U_i)}$. Suppose that $U \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(k)$ is open and that $s \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n(k)}(U)$. The sets $V_i := f^{-1}(U\cap U_i)$ form an open covering of $f^{-1}(U)$. For the functions $t_i := s \circ {f_i}_{|V_i} \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)}(V_i)$, we have $${t_i}_{|V_i\cap V_j}=s\circ f_{|f^{-1}(U\cap U_i\cap U_j)}={t_j}_{|V_i\cap V_j}.$$ Hence, they define a function $t\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)}(f^{-1}(U))$. On the other hand, $t$ is, by construction, nothing else but $s\circ f_{|f^{-1}(U)}$. Hence, $f$ is a morphism of prevarieties.

Comment: Thx a lot. That was quiet easy. I guess what I need is somebody who gives me easy problems which I try to solve and when I have worked out a solution he would go through it and correct it.